# How many ways can we colour the vertices of a 20 sided regular polygon with exactly 8 colors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

Could someone tell me if my reasoning and, therefore, result are correct?

The number asked is $p(m)-|\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} X_i|$, where $p(m)$ is the number of colorings with m colors (I'm doing first with m colors) and $X_i$ is the set of the colorings that doesn't use color $i$:$\;\;$
$p(m)-|\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} X_i|=p(m)-\sum_{j=1}^{m}(-1)^{j-1}{m\choose j}p(m-j)=\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}{m\choose j}p(m-j)$

The symmetries of a 20 sided regular polygon can be summarized in the following way:

$i)$ $20$ rotations by an angle of $\frac{\Pi}{10}$;

$ii) 10$ reflexions about an axis that connects 2 oposite vertices and passes through the center;

$iii)10$ reflexions about an axis that connects 2 oposite edges and passes throught the center;

$iv)$ the "identity" transformation.

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation that makes the polygon rotate by an angle of $\frac{\Pi}{10}$:

$\sigma$ -> 1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$;

$\sigma^2$->2 cycles of lenght 10 -> $m^2$;

$\sigma^3$->1 cycle of lenght 20->m

$\sigma^4$->4 cycles of lenght 5->m^4

$\sigma^5$->5 cycles of lenght 4 -> $m^5$

$\sigma^6$->2 cycles of lenght 10 -> $m^2$

$\sigma^7$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

$\sigma^8$->4 cycles of lenght 5 -> $m^4$

$\sigma^9$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

$\sigma^{10}$->10 cycles of lenght 2 -> $m^{10}$

$\sigma^{-1}=\sigma^{19}$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

$\sigma^{-2}=\sigma^{18}$->2 cycles of lenght 10 -> $m^2$

$\sigma^{-3}=\sigma^{17}$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

$\sigma^{-4}=\sigma^{16}$->4 cycles of lenght 5 -> $m^4$

$\sigma^{-5}=\sigma^{15}$->5 cycles of lenght 4 -> $m^5$

$\sigma^{-6}=\sigma^{14}$->2 cycles of lenght 10 -> $m^2$

$\sigma^{-7}=\sigma^{13}$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

$\sigma^{-8}=\sigma^{12}$->4 cycles of lenght 5 -> $m^4$

$\sigma^{-9}=\sigma^{11}$->1 cycle of lenght 20 -> $m$

Which give us $m^{20}+m^{10}+2m^5+4m^4+4m^2+8m$

Each one of the $(ii)$ reflexions has 2 cycles of lenght 1 and 9 of lenght 2 -> $10m^{11}$
Each one of the $(iii)$ reflexions has 10 cycles of lenght 2 -> $10m^{10}$.
The identity has 20 cycles of lenght 1 -> $m^20$

Therefore, by the Cauchy-Frobenius-Burnside Theorem we have:
$p(m) = \frac{1}{40}(m^{20}+10m{11}+11m^{10}+2m^5+4m^4+2m^2+8m)$

$\frac{1}{40}\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{j}{m\choose j}[(m-j)^{20}+10(m-j){11}+11(m-j)^{10}+2(m-j)^5+4(m-j)^4+2(m-j)^2+8(m-j)]$

Finally substituing by 8 we get:

$\frac{1}{40}\sum_{j=0}^{8}(-1)^{j}{8\choose j}[(8-j)^{20}+10(8-j){11}+11(8-j)^{10}+2(8-j)^5+4(8-j)^4+2(8-j)^2+8(8-j)]$